flutter ffi can't find .so file
I tried to execute .so file (golang file build for android) on android via flutter dart FFI. Everything works just fine when I do the same with .dll file on windows.
FFI exits with error:
E/flutter (12713): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'assets/lib.so': dlopen failed: library "assets/lib.so" not found
E/flutter (12713): #0      _open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:11:43)
E/flutter (12713): #1      new DynamicLibrary.open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:22:12)
E/flutter (12713): #2      dylib (package:proof2/fficheck.dart:7:34)
E/flutter (12713): #3      dylib (package:proof2/fficheck.dart)
E/flutter (12713): #4      runServer (package:proof2/fficheck.dart:10:5)
E/flutter (12713): #5      runServer (package:proof2/fficheck.dart)
E/flutter (12713): #6      main (package:proof2/main.dart:11:3)
E/flutter (12713): #7      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:301:23)
E/flutter (12713): #8      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
E/flutter (12713): #9      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

The code snippet. lib is in /assets/ directory
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart';

typedef run_server = ffi.Pointer<Utf8> Function(); // FFI fn signature
typedef RunServer = ffi.Pointer<Utf8> Function(); // Dart fn signature
final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open('assets/lib.so');

final RunServer runServer =
    dylib.lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<run_server>>('RunServer').asFunction();


The assets folder isn't going to be available at run time. You could load the so from assets, store to a temporary file, and then open that. Or follow the instructions here to add the so to gradle.

In Android, you can't access assets as normal file like in Windows, since it is packaged in a binary form.
To bundle prebuilt 3rd party library, you might want to add .so files to android/src/main/jniLibs/[abi]. Then you should be able to load the library via DynamicLibrary.open('libfoo.so'). This is doucmented here.
You need to provide a library for every ABI, so as a result, your project structure should look like this.
.
└── android/
    └── src/
        └── main/
            └── jniLibs/
                ├── arm64-v8a/
                │   └── libfoo.so
                ├── armeabi-v7a/
                │   └── libfoo.so
                ├── x86/
                │   └── libfoo.so
                └── x86_64/
                    └── libfoo.so

Else, as Richard Heap mentioned, you can copy .so from assets to application storage as file with following code snippet.
But I think it's less of a headache to let Gradle manage the libraries for you via jniLibs than it is to decide which .so files to load for each ABI yourself.
Future<File> getFileFromAssets(String assetPath, String filename) async {
  final Directory docDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final String localPath = docDir.path;
  final String targetFilePath = '$localPath/$filename';
  File targetFile = File(targetFilePath);
  final asset = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
  final buffer = asset.buffer;
  return targetFile.writeAsBytes(
      buffer.asUint8List(asset.offsetInBytes, asset.lengthInBytes));
}

